# Warning : Overriding commands for target Android Makefile

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I've got an issue building my C++ code using NDK r9d, since I try to compile C files using C++ compiler (G++) I've got this warnings :

```
C:/Android/ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:393: warning: overriding commands for target
C:/Android/ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:391: warning: ignoring old commands for target
```

Before I didn't need to compile with C++ 11 and my C files was compiled with GCC, I had no problems, but since I had `LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp .c`, this warnings appears (only for C files).

I found that someone else had the same problem ([Overriding commands for target Android Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481999/overriding-commands-for-target-android-makefile)) but didn't get any answer.

Here is my files :

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

MY_INC_PATH := ../../..
LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -std=c++11
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -ldl -llog -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(MY_INC_PATH)
MY_SRC_PATH := ../../../..
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp .c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(MY_SRC_PATH)/XXX.c \
    $(MY_SRC_PATH)/YYY.cpp \
    $(MY_SRC_PATH)/ZZZ.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I use NDK r9d and compile with G++ 4.8 and C++ 11 activated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you compile C files as C++?

Comment: Because the library wrote in C, use now some C++ code for a random generator from the std. The library is not mine, I will see if I can change it to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of r9d, NDK does not provide methods to unassociate `.c` files from C compiler. You can redefine `$$(TARGET_CC)`, and also set `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11`, and *not set* `LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION` to include `.c`, but that would be a hack, anyways. So if you cannot rename the files, and do not want to hack your NDK, the cleanest solution would be to simply ignore the warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's clear. I will try to rename the files if my client agree, othewise just ignore. Cheers.